# Show that any relation which is both symmetric and antisymmetric must be the empty relation.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So for symmetry, aRb implies bRa. And for antisymmetry, aRb implies not bRa. I don't know how to proceed in this proof from there. I think I'd be skipping a lot of steps if I said that proves that R is the empty relation. Or at least I should justify it in some way. I'm just not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true.  A relation where elements may only be related to themselves is both symmetric and antisymmetric, but not necessarily empty.

Symmetry : $\forall a\in A\,\forall B \in A \;(a R b = b R a)$

Antisymmetry: $\forall a\in A\,\forall B \in A \;(a R b \wedge b R a \to a=b)$

---

Example: the relation $R=\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$ of the set $A= \{0, 1\}$, is both symmetric and antisymmetric, and it is not empty.

---

"**Asymetry**" is the property where $\forall a\in A\; \forall b \in A\;( aR b \to \neg( bR a))$

A relation which is both symmetric and asymmetric must be empty because: Argument by contradiction .

> If there is any element $(a, b)$ in the relation, we have both that $(b, a)$ is in the relation (by symmetry) and that $(b, a)$ is *not* in the relation (by asymmetry). Which is contradictory, so $R$ must be empty.

Comment: My book was defining a = b as "weakly antisymmetric".

.. Looking up that term I think my book is being unique.

Comment: @Chylomicron "**Assymetry**" is the property where $\forall a\in A\; \forall b \in A\; aR b \to \not bR a$

Answer (score 1):

Argue by contradiction. Suppose instead that $R$ isn't empty. Then there exist some $x$ and $y$ such that $(x, y) \in R$. Since $R$ is symmetric, this implies that $(y, x) \in R$. But since $R$ is antisymmetric, we also know that $(y, x) \notin R$, a contradiction. So $R$ is indeed empty, as desired.

Comment: Ohh alright, that was easy. For some reason that just wasn't coming to me.

Thanks!